# Removal of red camp cards from the camp board

Tags: castaways

In **Castaways**, the red camp cards stay in the camp board until they are "dealt with". There are some camp cards, such as #51 (Argument), that have no clear condition stating how to "deal with" the card. Does this means that the card stays forever in the camp board, or that after a player triggers its effects it should be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from the [BBG forum](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1139035/removal-of-red-camp-cards-from-the-camp-board). There is no explicit information about this in the [manual](http://www.homoludicus.org/naufragos/RulesENSmall.pdf), neither in the [spanish FAQ](http://www.homoludicus.org/sites/default/files/FAQ.pdf). Without specific rules, it is reasonable to admit that red cards that do not explicitly define a removal condition (such as #51) stay in the camp board until the end of the game.